# I can't see bend on bones in Edit mode

Tags: bones

I do not see instant bending during rotating bone in Edit Mode. I have to go back to Object mode and after then I can see the bend. Thank you for advice[image]

Comment: Use Pose Mode instead of edit mode. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmt7T.gif